# glob.glob doesn't return any result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know what is wrong with my code. When I changed a location of file it works. But when I come to the folder which I need I didn't get any results. I checked the location, searched for specific png file as (`'*/*.png'`), the result is same. Could you please advise me, what can cause to this.

```
import os, glob
file_path = "/Users/XXXX/Desktop/png"
my_png_path = os.path.join(file_path, '*/*')
for my_files in glob.glob(my_png_path):
   print(my_files)
```

Comment: Which location worked?

Comment: any folder in the Desktop works. But specifically this folder not

Comment: also folder and file permissions are same with others

Comment: Uppercase **Png** by any chance?

Comment: `*/*` will not output any file if they are not in a subfolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on

```
file_path = "/Users/XXXX/Desktop/png"
my_png_path = os.path.join(file_path, '*/*')
```

The value of `my_png_path` is sth. like `/Users/XXXX/Desktop/png/*/*`, but I guess your intention is `/Users/XXXX/Desktop/*/*.png`, so the code should like

```
file_path = "/Users/XXXX/Desktop"
my_png_path = os.path.join(file_path, '*/*.png')
```

Comment: i think `*.png` should be relevant in this case or even `*.*` to match any extension